# shading the region on the complex plan

Tags: complex-numbers

It is not part of the homework, but it is preparations for the final exams. I have the following questions:

> For each of the following descriptions of a set of complex numbers, shade its region on the complex plane.
>
> 1. $\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \;\middle|\; |z - i| \leq 1\right\}$
> 2. $\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \;\middle|\; \dfrac{z-\bar{z}}{z+\bar{z}} = i,\;\; z + \bar{z} \neq 0\right\}$

I haven't found anything related to these questions in my textbook. Can someone give me a hint on how to approach these problems?

Comment: You could start by picking points, trying to find ones that satisfy the given conditions. Then start finding the edge cases that satisfy those conditions to map out the region in the complex plane they describe. While you are doing this, you should start to pick up a geometric sense of what those conditions imply.

Comment: Writing $z$ as $x+iy$ for real $x,y$, then $|z - i| \le 1 \iff \sqrt{x^2 + (y-1)^2} \le 1$ and $\frac{z-\bar{z}}{z+\bar{z}} = i \iff \frac{2yi}{2x} = i \iff \frac{y}{x} = 1$...

Comment: @achillehui why did you get rid of i in square root?

Comment: $|z - i| = |x + iy - i| = |x + (y-1)i| = \sqrt{x^2 + (y-1)^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let's consider the set $\{z\in\mathbb C \mid \vert z-i\vert \leq 1\}.$ It is quite elementary to show that $\vert x-y\vert$, is the distance between the two complex nubers $x$ and $y$. So we are looking for all $z\in\mathbb C$ for which the distance to the number $i$ is less than or equal to $1$. Now what shape does that define?
2. Let's consider the set $\left\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\dfrac {z-\bar z}{z+\bar z}=i,\quad z+\bar z\neq 0\right\}$. Now note that $z-\bar z=2i\Im (z)$ and $z+\bar z = 2\Re(z)$. This means that $\dfrac {z-\bar z}{z+\bar z}=i\dfrac{\Im (z)}{\Re(z)}$. Now if we want $i\dfrac{\Im(z)}{\Re(z)}=i$, we must have $\Re(z)=\Im(z)$. So we are looking for all $z\in \mathbb C$ for which $\Re(z)=\Im(z)$, with the exeption of the ones for which $z+\bar z =0$. Now what shape does that define?